# Linear interpolation in matlab using columns of data

Tags: matlab, distance, velocity, linear-interpolation

I have some travel time data stored as column vectors. I want to write a script that will allow me run a linear interpolation from specified initial and final values, to make a column of distances, so I can calculate velocity.

example: Column 1:  t1,t2,t3......tn; Column 2: (using the linear interpolation we create) d1, d2, d3....dn

So here we have generated a distance for each travel time based on an initial distance and a final distance.

then it should be simple to generate a new column that is simply the interpolated distances / travel times. Thanks for your help. Cheers

Comment: Have you tried `interp1`?

Comment: haven't tired anything yet. Fairly new to this

Answer (score 0):

`interp1` is your friend here:

```
% from zero to one hour
measuredTime = [0 1];

% from 0 to 100 km
measuredDistance = [0 100];

% 10 minute intervals
intermediateTimes = measuredTime(1):10/60:measuredTime(end);

% interpolated distances
intermediateDistances = interp1(measuredTime,measuredDistance,intermediateTimes);
```

Comment: How can this be modified to read a column of existing arrival time data and create a distance value for each value in the existing column? Cheers

Comment: Without seeing your data it's hard to answer your specific question. This page should get you started: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Arrays/Basic_vector_operations

Comment: I have one column with some numbers in it. I need to make another column next to it that contains some interpolated values. the values need to increase linearly between two numbers that I can set as the start and finish for the interpolation.

Comment: @MVaughan Please update the question with the relevant information rather than making comments.